# Serverless framework with python and aws lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

When i import a function from another file and do the deploy it doesn't work.
It gives me: error 500 internal server error. The python requirements works fine, because the hello function doesn't give me an error. But getPrediction doesn't work well

In offline mode all works fine.

My handler.js

```
try:
    import unzip_requirements
except ImportError:
    pass

import json
import numpy
import scipy
from predictions.make_prediction import make_prediction

def hello(event, context):

    response = {"statusCode": 200, "body": {mod.__name__: mod.__version__ for mod in (numpy, scipy)}}
    return response 

def getPrediction(event, context):
    hola = make_prediction([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
    response = {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps(hola.tolist())}
    return response
```

My serverless.yml

```
service: enno-searcher
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  timeout: 29

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-python-requirements

package:
 patterns:
   - '!node_modules/**'
   - '!Lib/**'
   - '!README.md'
   - '!build/**'
   - '!__pycache__/**'
   - '!Include/**'

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    zip: true

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get
  getPrediction:
    handler: handler.getPrediction
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /get-prediction
          method: get
```

I've tried changing the way I import external functions, but it keeps giving me the same error. maybe i'm doing it wrong

I have also tried not to import functions from other files. I've tried bringing the code from make_prediction to getPrediction, but it keeps giving me an error.

Comment: What was the error you get when you tried putting make_prediction() inside your handler.py ?

Comment: {"message":"Internal Server Error"}

Comment: Can you check the logs on your CloudWatch logs for that lambda function? is there any detailed message on the logs?

Comment: `INIT_START Runtime Version: python:3.7.v22 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:c20bdb59d3d6e84cc4b436e730261b773590c43962e79e9b7a43e9715ac5276d

OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k

START  Version: $LATEST

REPORT  Duration: 15764.24 ms Billed Duration: 15765 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 639 MB

START  Version: $LATEST

REPORT  Duration: 5.13 ms Billed Duration: 6 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 639 MB

`

Comment: On your question you said it's handler.js , are you sure?

Comment: Is handler.py sorry. How should the structure of my files be? How should I import my functions?

Comment: Can you post your current project structure so I can take a look at it?

Comment: My Main folder is the python virtual environment. For that reason it has the Scripts folder. Also, my main folder is the serverless framework project. I'll give you my folder structure. 
+enno-searcher .gitignore application.py dic.csv handler.py package-lock.json package.json pyvenv.cfg README.md requirements.txt searcher.py serverless.yml tree.joblib
+---.serverless cloudformation-template-create-stack.json cloudformation-template-update-stack.json serverless-state.json
+---Lib
+---node_modules
+---predictionsªmake_prediction.pyªsave_prediction_model.py
+---Scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem with serverless framework. After many tests, this is how my files "handler.py" and my "serverless.yml" have stayed

serverless.yml

```
service: enno-searcher
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  timeout: 29
  httpApi:
    cors: true

package:
  patterns:
   - '!node_modules/**'
   - '!Lib/**'
   - '!README.md'
   - '!build/**'
   - '!__pycache__/**'
   - '!Include/**'

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get
  test:
    handler: handler.test
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /test
          method: get
  getprediction:
    handler: handler.getPrediction
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /get-prediction
          method: get

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    zip: true
```

handler.py

```
try:
    import unzip_requirements
except ImportError:
    pass

import json

def hello(event, context):
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True
        },
        "body": 'Searcher Backend v0.0.1'}
    return response

def test(event, context):
    from predictions.make_prediction import make_prediction
    hola = make_prediction([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True
        },
        "body": json.dumps(
        hola.tolist()
    )}
    return response 

def getPrediction(event, context):
    try:
        from predictions.make_prediction import make_prediction
        inputPrediction = event['queryStringParameters']['prediction']
        prediction = make_prediction(eval(inputPrediction))
        response = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True
            },
            "body": json.dumps(
            prediction.tolist()
        )}
        return response
    
    except KeyError as e:
        error_message = f'Faltan los parametros requeridos: {e}'
        response = {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True
            },
            'body': json.dumps({'error': error_message})
        }
        return response
    
    except Exception as e:
        # Captura cualquier otra excepción y devuelve un mensaje de error genérico
        error_message = f'Se produjo un error al procesar la solicitud: {e}'
        response = {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True
            },
            'body': json.dumps({'error': error_message})
        }
        return response
```

In this way, I have already managed to import functions from other documents. By importing it inside each function, I manage to contain the errors. I've also added try and except to further handle errors. I have also added cors to the APIs.

In addition, I have added many more functions (which I have not put here), with the same structure as the "getPrediction" function. They have all worked perfectly for me.